# Jacobian matrix of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus

Suppose we had a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y,z)=x+2y+3z$

What is the jacobian matrix?

Is it simply $(1 \space\space 2 \space\space\space 3$)? Are row vectors considered matrices as well?

Comment: The short answer is yes.

Answer (score 3):

The Jacobian can be a row or column vector, which is to say a matrix with only one row or column. As CoffeeBliss says, the Jacobian of a function $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.

There is an operation called the **gradient** of $f$ and it is defined by:

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla} f= \begin{bmatrix}\ \partial_xf \ \ \ \partial_yf \ \ \ \partial_zf \ \end{bmatrix}$$

The symbol $\nabla$ is called **nabla**.

Note that the gradient as I defined it is a **row** vector and that the Jacobian $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial(x,y,z)}$ would be a **column** vector. However, it's often convenient to not distinguish between the two, and so it's common to consider the gradient as a specific case of the Jacobian where the codomain is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the Jacobian matrix. Given any differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, the Jacobian matrix is an $m \times n$ matrix.